# Updating an element in Javascript 2D array updates entire column

Tags: javascript, arrays, pointers, matrix, multidimensional-array

I created a 2D array (4x4) in Javascript like this:

```
let visited = new Array(4).fill(new Array(4).fill(false));
console.log(visited);

[
  [ false, false, false, false ],
  [ false, false, false, false ],
  [ false, false, false, false ],
  [ false, false, false, false ]
]
```

When I tried to update a single element, it ends up updating entire column. Why is this happening?

```
visited[0][0] = true;
console.log(visited);
```

You can see this [repl](https://repl.it/repls/UnwelcomeDizzyBaitware)

Expected:

```
[
  [ true, false, false, false ],
  [ false, false, false, false ],
  [ false, false, false, false ],
  [ false, false, false, false ]
]
```

Actual:

```
[
  [ true, false, false, false ],
  [ true, false, false, false ],
  [ true, false, false, false ],
  [ true, false, false, false ]
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The docs of [`Array.fill`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill) are your friend here:

> Note all elements in the array will be this exact value.

This is telling you that each one of the sub-arrays are actually the SAME array. Thus, if you change one, you change them all.

Looking at the code below, you'll see that the first comparison is `false`, whereas the second comparison is `true`

```js
console.log([false,false,false,false] ===[false,false,false,false])

const arr = new Array(4).fill([false,false,false,false]);

console.log(arr[0] === arr[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Construct your Matrix with loops, rather than `new Array().fill()`

```
  let visited = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    visited.push([]);
    for (let j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
      visited[i].push(false);
    }
  }

  visited[0][0] = true;
  console.log(visited);
```

Answer (score 0):

my friend change the way you create the matrix, just checkout this variant with .map():

```
 let visited = 
    (new Array(4)).fill().map(function(){ return new Array(4).fill(false);});
    visited[0][0] = true;
    console.log(visited)
    
    0: (4) [true, false, false, false]
    1: (4) [false, false, false, false]
    2: (4) [false, false, false, false]
    3: (4) [false, false, false, false]
```

Peace :)

Comment: Nice! It can be even cleaner like this: `let visited = (new Array(4)).fill().map(x => new Array(4).fill(false));`

Comment: @JAM, for sure that is a clean way and more simple